# Convert multiple .xls files to .xlsx in ssis

Tags: sql, vbscript, ssis

I have a folder that receives multiple excel files in `.xls format`. I need to change the format type to `.xlsx` in order to load the excel data into SQLvia SSIS. I know how to rename the file using "**File System Task**" but that works for a specific file. but my file contains a file # and date as well that needs to stay same as source file, I only want the file type to change and the file move to a processed folder. Can anyone help me?

```
Source Path: C:\Documents\TestFolder
Source File: TestSegRpt_0001_2017_02_22.xls

Destination Path: C:\Documents\TestFolderProcessed
Destination File: TestSegRpt_0001_2017_02_22.xlsx
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoping i understood your problem correctly.

I think below link will help.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other/batch-convert-xls-to-xlsx/1d9b3d78-daf0-4014-8fb2-930aca6493b0

Comment: is that a VB Script? sorry I'm new to scripting

Comment: @Syed Jafri If you are new to scripting or creating macros i think you can use some kind of software. Just found this link on google http://ccm.net/download/download-18703-convert-xls-to-xlsx. Please check if this can help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `Script Task`, loop over files, and use a function like the following to create *precessed* directory and convert files *(code in Vb.net)*:

```
Public Sub ConvertXlsToXlsx(ByVal strpath as string)

    Dim strDirectory as string = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strpath) & "Processed"

    If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(strDirectory) Then System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(strDirectory)

    Dim xl As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook

    xlWorkBook = xl.Workbooks.Open(strpath)
    xlBook.SaveAs(strDirectory & "\" & System.IO.Path.GetFilename(strpath) & "x")
    xl.Application.Workbooks.Close()
    xl.Application.Quit()

End Sub
```

Your code will look like:

```
Public Sub Main

    Dim strFolder as string = Dts.Variables.Item("FolderPath").Value

    Dim strXlsFiles() as string = IO.Directory.GetFiles(strFolder,"*.xlsx",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)

    For each strFile as String in strXlsFiles

        If strFile.EndsWith("xlsx") The Continue For 

        ConvertXlsToXlsx(strFile)

    Next


End Sub
```

**Reference:**

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a73f846c-91ee-4dad-bd7b-c04d418d0561/convert-xls-into-xlsx?forum=exceldev